# Spring Cloud Gateway in AWS not routing correctly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I have created a simple REST service as below:

```
@RestController
public class ServiceController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/getSimpleResponse")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getSimpleResponse() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Hello from Service 1", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

I deploy this to AWS elastic beanstalk and is working fine. Here: [Service 1 in AWS](http://testservice1-env.qgwe5a4qq8.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/getSimpleResponse)

Now I create a Spring Cloud Gateway service with route configuration as below:

```
@Configuration
public class GatewayConfig {
    @Bean
    public RouteLocator gatewayRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route(getFirstTestServiceRoute())
                .build();
    }

    private Function<PredicateSpec, Route.AsyncBuilder> getFirstTestServiceRoute() {
        return p -> p
                .path("/service1/**")
                .uri("http://testservice1-env.qgwe5a4qq8.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/")
                .id("service1");
    }
}
```

I Deploy the Gateway Application in AWS Elastic beanstalk [here](http://testapplicationgateway-env.jraypxr8ta.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/).

But the [GatewayURL/service1/getSimpleResponse](http://testapplicationgateway-env.jraypxr8ta.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/service1/getSimpleResponse) returns a Whitelabel Error Page. I was expecting the same output as Service 1. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If the downstream service doesn't respond to /service1 you need to modify the path, with, for example, a StripPrefix 1 filter

Comment: @spencergibb I am new to this whole thing. Would you be kind enough to give me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing RequestMapping at the class level. My URL format is

> GatewayURL/service1/getSimpleResponse

I assume this is because the Spring Cloud Gateway is probably appending the complete path(/service1/getSimpleResponse) to the downstream service URL

```
 @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/service1")
    public class ServiceController {

        @GetMapping(value = "/getSimpleResponse")
        public ResponseEntity<String> getSimpleResponse() {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Hello from Service 1", HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to open URL, that you set in your Gateway, in a browser and you will see the same Whitelabel Error Page.
Your endpoint is /getSimpleResponse but your Gateway doesn't know about it. There is no magic in it, it works according to your configuration.

Moreover your stack will not work locally too. Start with making it work locally and only then move it piece by piece to the cloud.